# Complexity of computing logarithm of a prime power

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, nt.number-theory, primes

Suppose $n = p^k$ for some prime number $p$ and some non-negative integer $k$. What is (the best-known upper bound on) the complexity of computing $k$ on input $n$ (given in binary)? It is important to note that the prime is unknown. The input is just a number $n$.

It seems that there exists [1] an algorithm for computing $k$ when $n$ is a power of an arbitrary integer (not necessarily a prime) that runs in $O(\log n \log^c \log n)$ time for some $c$. Is there a better algorithm for prime powers?

[1]: [Bernstein, Lenstra, and Pila. *Detecting Perfect powers by factoring into coprimes*, 2006.](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-257/S0025-5718-06-01837-0/)

Comment: Is “some number p” a typo for “some prime p”?

Comment: The title is misleading. Discrete log refers to modular arithmetic.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Yes, that was a typo, thank you.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I will change it.